# how to list all android projects Github using Github API?

Tags: java, android, github, full-text-search

I am looking for a URL form Github API to list all android project, 
for Example I can use this api to list all java project 
https://api.github.com/legacy/repos/search/language=java

Comment: `https://api.github.com/legacy/repos/search/language=android` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add topics as a parameter to your API call.

Try something like: `https://api.github.com/search/topics?q=android&language=java`

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.mercy-preview+json' \
'https://api.github.com/search/topics?q=android&language=java'
```